# Logs are not getting generated from war file using log4j which is in Jboss 6.0.1 instance

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

During run of a war application from Jboss 6.0.1, I faced a issue that logs are not getting generated. So first thing I checked log4j.properties, and I found it correctly defined. Then after I checked log4j jar file which is in the Jboss-->Server--> Instance Name-->lib, and file was there so everything was correct for running war application. But still logs were not generating.

Final attempt which I did, I placed log4j jar file in war\web-inf\lib dir. And I found everything was working. I couldn't understand, why it was not picking same jar file from instance lib? Is there any other configuration missing or Is this a issue?

Comment: Do you mean JBoss AS6? in this release log4j is configured from ../deploy/jboss-logging.xml

Comment: yes it is there in, jboss-6.1.1\server\omniflow\deploy\jboss-logging.xml